# Проблема с извлечением байт из бд

Tags: python, база-данных

Есть бд в mySQL, один из столбцов имеет тип BLOB(байты).
Но при извлечении и использовании его в дальнейшем, мне указывает, что это тип данных кортеж.
В связи с чем у меня в коде вот такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\socket\database.py", line 181, in <module>
new_password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', new_password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

А вот собственно сам код. Это извлечение кэшированного пароля из бд и соли. А после проверка совпадают ли пароли в бд и введенный пользователем пароль.

```
def sign_in(login):

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        password="soldan1512",
        database="chat_base",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print("Successfully connected...")
    print("#" * 20)

    try:

        # insert data

        values = (login, )
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            select_password = "SELECT password FROM registration_table WHERE login = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_password, values)
            rows_password = cursor.fetchall()
            select_salt = "SELECT password FROM registration_table WHERE login = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_salt, values)
            rows_salt = cursor.fetchall()
            print("#" * 20)
            return rows_password, rows_salt



    finally:
        connection.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)
password, salt = sign_in('danila')
new_password = '123'
new_password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', new_password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
if password == new_password:
    print('yes')
```

Данные в бд есть, и слово по которому я извлекаю данные из бд, тоже там присутствует

Comment: .fetchall() возвращает tuple, нет? и return rows_password, rows_salt вернет два кортежа... и потом salt в виде кортежа уходит в hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac()

Comment: @Jack_oS он возвращает их пустыми, а такого быть не должно

Comment: так может просто нет таких данных

Comment: @splash58 они там есть, потому что я их туда сам внес. И я писал выше что данные там есть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Извлечение данных из бд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286979/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b4)