# Извлечение данных из бд

Tags: python, база-данных

Нужно извлечь данные из бд(mysql). Один из столбцов содержит байты, но при извлечении они выводятся в виде списка. Тип данных у этого столбца BLOB

```
[{'salt': b'y\xa4\xe3Z\x0c\x1b\x17\xc6-\x05\x8d\x01\x81*\x0c5\r\xf03;\x83\x90W\x12\x8d;\x82"\xc7V\xe0\x98'}]
```

Вот код через, который я использовал:

```
def sign_in_password(id):
try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        password="soldan1512",
        database="chat_base",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )

    try:


        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            values = (id, )
            select_password = "SELECT password FROM registration_table WHERE id = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_password, values)
            rows_password = cursor.fetchone()
            rows_password = str(rows_password)
            rows_password = rows_password[13:-2]
            select_salt = "SELECT salt FROM registration_table WHERE id = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_salt, values)
            rows_salt = cursor.fetchall()
            print(rows_salt)
            #return rows_password, rows_salt



    finally:
        connection.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)
```

Как это можно исправить.

Comment: Какой результат ожидаете получить?

Comment: @Roman Konoval байты мне нужны. Это ключ для шифрования паролей. И мне нужно проверить правильный ли пароль ввел пользователь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в результате запроса всегда будет одна запись возвращаться, то так:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
key = row['salt']
```